# Process a FIFO Queue but drop items if they are too old

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

I've written a [basic utility](https://github.com/jasonsperske/PubNubBlink) that listens for messages in one thread, adds them to a FIFO queue and processes them in another thread.  Each message takes a fixed time to process (it's waiting for a blinking light to stop blinking), but messages can arrive randomly (`patterns` in the code is a dictionary of regexes to match the incoming message to, if a match is found it adds it to the queue along with a color pattern to blink).

```
blink_queue = Queue()
def receive(data) :
    message = data['text']

    for pattern in patterns:
        if re.match(pattern, message):
            blink_queue.put(patterns[pattern])
            break
    return True

def blinker(q) :
    while True:
        args = q.get().split()
        subprocess.Popen(
            [blink_app] + args,
            startupinfo=startupinfo,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(blink_wait)
        q.task_done()

def subscribe():
    print("Listening for messages on '%s' channel..." % channel)
    pubnub.subscribe({
        'channel'  : channel,
        'callback' : receive
    })

blink_worker = Thread(target=blinker, args=(blink_queue,))
blink_worker.daemon=True
blink_worker.start()

sub_thread = Thread(target=subscribe)
sub_thread.daemon=True
sub_thread.start()

sub_thread.join()
```

How do I implement a FIFO Queue in Python that automatically trims the oldest (first) queue if it grows to big.  Do I create another watching thread, or do I keep the size in check on the `subscribe` thread? I'm really new at Python, so if there is a totally logical Data Type please feel free to call me a noob and send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out there is a logical type [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque).  From the documentation:

> If maxlen is not specified or is None, deques may grow to an arbitrary
>   length. Otherwise, the deque is bounded to the specified maximum
>   length. Once a bounded length deque is full, when new items are added,
>   a corresponding number of items are discarded from the opposite end.

(and [here](https://github.com/jasonsperske/PubNubBlink/commit/dc45082fc77ebbcaf20c575e616917eca4eeaf0d) is the commit that implements this datatype)

Answer (score 1):

For this I would subclass [Queue](http://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) and overload the `put` method to remove items in the fashion you desire if the `Queue` gets too large.

e.g.

```
class NukeOldDataQueue(Queue.Queue):
    def put(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.full():
            try:
                oldest_data = self.get()
                print('[WARNING]: throwing away old data:'+repr(oldest_data))
            # a True value from `full()` does not guarantee
            # that anything remains in the queue when `get()` is called
            except Queue.Empty:
                pass
        Queue.Queue.put(self,*args,**kwargs)
```

You may also want to pass the `block=False` parameter or manipulate the `timeout` parameter depending on how bad it is to accidentally throw away new data or whether blocking on the `put()` call is acceptable.

Comment: I know this is old, but if you do this, you should lock since it's possible that the state of the queue will change before checking if it's full and calling `get()`, and also between that and `put()`